# Second monitor resolution messed up

Tags: display, display-resolution

Today I opened my computer (laptop). My second monitor now has fullHD resolution instead of 4k. Ubuntu version is 23.10. How can I fix the issue? The highest resolution in the settings list is fullHD now for some reason.

I know that the best way would be to buy Mac but it is a work laptop (not mine). The most expensive laptop that I've ever used in terms of unproductive work hours.

Comment: Is the monitor recognized by its proper brand and type name? Or just as a "generic" fullHD monitor? It may be as simple as a loose or broken cable. Sometimes even rebooting helps.

Comment: It seems to be recognized by at least correct brand name. I've rebooted, reconnected the monitor, changed cable (from thunderbolt to hdmi) and no any change at all. The list of resolutions ends at FullHD

Comment: I used different monitor for a brief moment yesterday before shutting down the computer. Maybe the system is stuck with the other monitor's settings. It was only fullhd monitor. I just don't understand how that could be possible... that would be unacceptably bad design if ubuntu doesn't understand that monitor could be changed to another one.

Comment: I also removed ~/.config/monitors.xml but it had zero effect on anything. Even after logging out and in again everything was exactly the same as before

Comment: I can assure you that Ubuntu's monitor detection is usually rather good. We can rule out bad design.

Comment: Well it did work really well up to this point and now it just completely stopped working correctly. Something like just how to completely reset wayland settings (or whatever does the monitor recognition) might be helpful.

Comment: I mean I'm not interested in technical jargon even though I work in tech. I don't need technical explanations. Anything that fixes the issue is greatly appreciated. I just want to do my work well with tools that do not cause me headache.

Comment: I connected the other monitor, old ASUS fullHD to this laptop. It says Ancor Communications Inc 24". And list of available resolutions is correct. I will next connect to the other display.

Comment: Now the new monitor ASUS 4k and settings say: Asustek computer inc 24" and list of resolutions still ends at fullhd. Maybe the monitor detection has a nasty bug or something... ?

Comment: Okay. So scaling was the issue. It just looked like a resolution problem and I was mistaken about the resolution of the monitor in use. Fiddling with scaling fixed it but I cannot figure out how it went wrong in the first place. :D

Comment: Good! Perhaps you may want to post a brief answer.